# Create flat, associative array from 2nd level values and 1st level keys of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, functional-programming, array-flip

I'm looking for a way to replace nested foreach loops with a functional programming approach.  Here is the sample data:

```
$mode[1] = [1, 2, 5, 6];
$mode[0] = [3, 4, 7, 8];
```

Currently my code is this:

```
foreach ($mode as $key => $value):
  foreach ($value as $v):
    $modes[$v] = $key;
  endforeach;
endforeach;

echo '<pre>' . print_r($modes, 1) . '</pre>';
```

This generates the desired output (which can be thought of as flipping a 2d array):

```
array (
  1 => 1,
  2 => 1,
  5 => 1,
  6 => 1,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  7 => 0,
  8 => 0,
)
```

Does anyone know how the foreach code block can be replaced with a functional programming alternative?

Comment: Use `array_map()`

Comment: Please do look at my answer. It was unfairly downvoted, but it's the shortest and simplest working solution to this question. I will add an extra code block in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `array_walk()` partnered with a Union Operator and `array_fill_keys()` seems like a clean choice for this task:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4a1a8cdfc052987b2703a003a9a655b2ad1eaec7))

```
$mode[1] = [1, 2, 5, 6];
$mode[0] = [3, 4, 7, 8];

$result = []; // declare empty array so that union operator works
array_walk($mode, function($a, $k) use (&$result) { $result += array_fill_keys($a, $k); });
var_export($result);
```

---

To avoid declaring any variables in the global scope, call `array_reduce()` on the first level keys and use those keys to access the second level subarray. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/043tB))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        array_keys($mode),
        fn($result, $k) => $result += array_fill_keys($mode[$k], $k),
        []
    )
);
```

Output (from either snippet):

```
array (
  1 => 1,
  2 => 1,
  5 => 1,
  6 => 1,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  7 => 0,
  8 => 0,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `array_map()`

```
array_map(function($key, $value) use (&$modes) {
    array_map(function($v) use (&$modes) {
        $modes[$v] = $key;
    }, $value);
}, array_keys($mode), array_values($mode));
```

I'm not sure *why* you would want to do this, the `foreach` version seems much clearer to me.

Comment: It is functional, but I agree with @Barmar that the `foreach` looks clearer.

Comment: This isn't functional at all since `&$modes` creates side effects and since you discard the return value of the outer/inner `map`.

Comment: @ftor I think he intended "functional" to mean "by calling higher-order functions", not in the side effect-free sense of pure functional programming.

Comment: Well, now the OP thinks FP leads to laborious and hard to follow code without any advantages being obtained. This isn't true for pure functional code. Anayway, maybe the FP tag should be replaced with higher-order-functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [array_fill_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) to create the mode arrays, then merge them into one:

```
$modes = array_fill_keys($mode[1], 1) + array_fill_keys($mode[0], 0);
```

For legibility, you can split it up into multiple lines, but this should get you an idea.

Bonus: you can abstract this code even more, if you don't know the contents of `$mode` exactly:

```
$modes = [];
foreach ($mode as $key => $value) {
    $modes += array_fill_keys($value, $key);
}
```

Comment: Can you generalize to more than just two elements?

Comment: Why the -1? This does exactly what the OP wants. You can always use a foreach to abstract this a bit more by making the `array_fill_keys` second argument equal to `$key`.

Comment: @K.thomas You are literally printing the wrong variable. You are printing `$mode` instead of `$modes` and if you correct that, you see the output is equal to the OP's.

Comment: You still have a `foreach` loop in the second version. Can you make that functional as well?

Comment: @Marijke Luttekes - your foreach approach is far superior to my original nested foreach loops.  However, I am really trying to find a functional programming solution for this problem.

Comment: @Barmar You're free to make your own answer. I like the foreach for this use case, it's got little overhead and it's very easy to read.

Comment: @knot22 Why does it have to be functional programming?

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes I did post my own answer.

Comment: @Marijke Luttekes This problem is particularly well suited to FP because all values are constants AND I am trying to learn how to implement FP in PHP.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry about that, I see it now.

Comment: @knot22 Well, considering you require both the key and value of the `$mode` array, you cannot use `array_map` as that one only handles values. You can try `array_walk`, but I can't imagine you'll get clean code out of it. I doubt you can make code that's less complicated and has less overhead than mine. You can take a shot at it and find a better solution, or you find a better test case than the one in your original question.

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes See my answer for how you can get the keys with `array_map`.

Comment: @Barmar I've seen it. A double `array_map` with pointers. Yes it does what the OP wants and in such, it's a good answer to this question and therefore I have upvoted it. However, I would never allow it in production code. You probably wouldn't either, given your comment below it.

Comment: Some context: I did not realize this was an exercise when I wrote the answer. Hence I went for clean code instead of FP (as that seems wrong in this use-case).

Answer (score -4):

use array_flip for exchange key and val together in array :

https://3v4l.org/DeIsG

but because of you want use multidimensional array you should have a loop :

```
<?php
$mode[0] = array(1, 2, 5, 6);
$mode[1] = array(3, 4, 7, 8);
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
 $flipped = array_flip($mode[$i]);
 print_r($flipped);
}
```

?>

output:

```
Array
(
[1] => 0
[2] => 1
[5] => 2
[6] => 3
)
Array
(
[3] => 0
[4] => 1
[7] => 2
[8] => 3
)
```

Comment: This output does not match the desired output the OP has presented.