# replace nested for-loops on multidimensional array with mclapply()

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, mclapply

I'm trying to perform an action over a 4-dimensional array. This array ends up being incredibly big, but is necessary for the data that i'm processing. Now the process itself goes swell, but i want to make it ready for parallel computing. I've got access to a 96-core mainframe and i want to use it.

So far i've read online that the easiest way to get this done is by using mclapply(), the parallelized version of lapply(). I know the basics of how lapply() works, but i can't quite figure out how to apply it in this situation.

I have a 4-dimensional array that's filled with NAs. Each dimension has dimnames. I want to compare the dimnames of dimension 1 with dimension 3 and dimension 2 with dimension 4 (this is done by a custom function that i wrote). If they all match up, a number comes out and i want that number to be entered into xy[i, k, j, l] where the letters i-l represent the indices for one entry.

In the example below i have simplified it into an addition of the nchar() values for the dimnames.

```
xy <- array(NA, dim = c(10, 10, 10, 10), dimnames = list(c("john", "sandra", "peter", "linda", "max", "sam", "ana", "enzo", "juan", "abe"), 
                                                          c("smith", "gonzalez", "doe", "dopi", "lincoln", "biden", "rutte", "merkel", "slim", "shady"),
                                                          c("jon", "sam", "pete", "melinda", "max", "sam", "anna", "carlo", "jiro", "abel"),
                                                          c("smitty", "rupinder", "dole", "mite", "lincolan", "bidet", "rourke", "meer", "smart", "sunny")))

for(i in 1:dim(xy)[1]){
    for(j in 1:dim(xy)[3]){
      for(k in 1:dim(xy)[2]){
        for(l in 1:dim(xy)[4]){
          a <- nchar(dimnames(xy)[[1]][i]) + nchar(dimnames(xy)[[3]][j])
          b <- nchar(dimnames(xy)[[2]][k]) + nchar(dimnames(xy)[[4]][l])
          if(!is.null(a) & !is.null(b)){
            xy[i, k, j, l] <- a + b
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

my problem is that my output needs to be a multidimensional array. so far i've only used lapply() to output one list of values. How do i extend this to multiple dimensions?

I've already looked in these posts:

[replace a nested for loop with mapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697281/replace-a-nested-for-loop-with-mapply)

[replace nested foreach loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588936/replace-nested-foreach-loops)

but each of these solve the question in a way that does not help mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun_on_names <- function(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4){
 
 a <- nchar(Var1) + nchar(Var3)
 b <- nchar(Var2) + nchar(Var4)
 
 if(!is.null(a) & !is.null(b)) return(a + b)
 else return(NA)
 
}

xy[] <- do.call(parallel::mcmapply, 
                c(list(FUN = fun_on_names, mc.cores = 96),
                  expand.grid(dimnames(xy), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
```

The idea is:

- create with `expand.grid` a big data.frame of all the combination of names you have.
- apply the function `fun_on_names` on each combination
- apply the result back to `xy`

The function actually returns a numeric vector, but by keeping `[]` in `xy[]<-`, you are assigning the values back to `xy` by keeping intact the attributes of `xy` which makes it a multidimensional array.

This solution does not work in parallel on Windows.

`do.call` is needed no that each column of the data.frame (output of `expand.grid`) is treated by `mcapply` as individual vectors.

You can see it as:

```
df <- expand.grid(dimnames(xy), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
xy[] <- parallel::mcmapply(FUN = fun_on_names, 
                           mc.cores = 96,
                           df[[1]], df[[2]], df[[3]], df[[4]])
```